# How to verify an option is selected with Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a Select tag with several options (pictured below). I want to write a selenium test where I verify that the option with the 18 value is selected.

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
`age_min = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('select#age-min > option[value="18"]')
 age_min_selected = is_attribtue_present(age_min, 'selected')
 self.assertTrue(age_min_selected)`
```

I get this error: `NameError: name 'is_attribtue_present' is not defined`

I've also tried this:

```
`age_min = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('select#age-min > option[value="18"]["selected"]')`
```

error: `Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the "selected" attribute on the `option` as such:

```
options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//option")

for option in options:
    is_selected = option.is_selected()
    print(str(is_selected))
```

Based on this documentation:

https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html?highlight=is_selected#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.is_selected